# mysql query runs fine in editor, won't run from PHP webserver

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

This query works perfectly from my mysql editor:

```
INSERT into brokercomps2 (company, memnumbers)
SELECT employee.company, count(*)
FROM employee, brokercomps
WHERE employee.company = brokercomps.company group by employee.company;
```

However, when I try to run from php webserver it fails:

```
sql6 = "INSERT into brokercomps2 (company, memnumbers) SELECT employee.company, count(*) FROM employee, brokercomps WHERE employee.company = brokercomps.company group by employee.company";
```

The user permissions are correct, and other queries run fine.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?  Do you get any errors?  Where do you actually run the query?  Do you check for MySQL errors?  You did remember to add the `$` before your variable, right?

Comment: I see you're new here. Please give the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) a read if you haven't already (spoiler alert, there's a badge in it for you).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a function like [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). I'd recommend [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) though.